# How to use Open Zeppelin subgraphs to query ERC721 balance?

Tags: tokens, erc-721, openzeppelin, the-graph, subgraph

I have created an Open Zeppelin subgraph so I can track many different `ERC20`, `ERC721` and `ERC1155` smart contracts.

My `config.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "output": "generated/sample.",
    "chain": "mainnet",
    "datasources": [
        { 
            "address": "0x8B0D1a282f132f67fc2018CeB797890D9C513710", 
            "startBlock": 31900771, 
            "module": [
                "erc20", 
                "ownable", 
                "accesscontrol"
            ] 
        },
        { 
            "address": "0x63dbcD091fBE539B70fB855bB941055e7EE80324", 
            "startBlock": 31895100, 
            "module": [
                "erc721", 
                "ownable", 
                "accesscontrol"
            ] 
        },
        { 
            "address": "0xDE7195E8865576A1c9Faae5f7c7d543967bF704E", 
            "startBlock": 32356993, 
            "module": [
                "erc1155", 
                "ownable", 
                "accesscontrol"
            ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to query my wallet to see how many `ERC721` tokens I have, like this:

```
{
  account(id: "0xfe02781cc0fe76Bfd2D211430bfa97D2889fd853") {
    ERC721tokens {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is I am getting this as a result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "account": {
      "ERC721tokens": []
    }
  }
}
```

I actually hold 2 tokens of `0x63dbcD091fBE539B70fB855bB941055e7EE80324` (you can check it [here](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xfe02781cc0fe76Bfd2D211430bfa97D2889fd853)).

How can I get the right balance of `ERC721`? My subgraph is 100% synced and has no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I wasn't updating my subgraph correctly.

Every time you make a modification to your `config.json`, you need to re-compile, re-create and re-deploy it with these commands:

```
npx graph-compiler --config configs/config.json --include node_modules/@openzeppelin/subgraphs/src/datasources --export-schema --export-subgraph


graph create generated/sample --node http://127.0.0.1:8020


graph deploy --ipfs http://localhost:5001 --node http://localhost:8020 generated/sample ./generated/sample.subgraph.yaml
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the graph, you can also use API providers to query the ERC721 balance from EVM blockchains. For example, you can use Moralis [`getWalletNFTs`](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/reference/get-wallet-nfts) API to do the same thing in a few lines of code.

Simply install the `moralis` package

```js
npm install moralis
```

and use the following code with your [API Key](https://admin.moralis.io)

```js
import Moralis  from 'moralis';
import { EvmChain } from '@moralisweb3/evm-utils';

try {
    const address = '0xfe02781cc0fe76Bfd2D211430bfa97D2889fd853';

    const chain = EvmChain.MUMBAI;

    await Moralis.start({
        apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
        // ...and any other configuration
    });

    const response = await Moralis.EvmApi.nft.getWalletNFTs({
        address,
        chain,
    });

    console.log(response?.result);
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

And you will the ERC721 balance easily just like that. Hope this helps

P.S. I work for Moralis